# Oracle Apex Tabular Form Data Lost

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, tabular-form

I have a Tabular Form in my Oracle Apex application. There is a column as `UPDATED_DATE`. I have set `Tabular Form Attributes` of this column as below.

[image: apex_tabular_form]

When i'm inserting data, `UPDATED_DATE` column in database table is filling with a value. But when i'm updating existing record, `UPDATED_DATE` column is not filling with a new value. old date is remaining without changing to a newer data.

How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

The default will only set a value if the field is empty. On your first entry the field is empty, and therefore the updated_Date is set. On updating, the field is allready set, and therefore won't be updated.

You need to create a dynamic action (assuming you use apex 4 or above) and use that to update the date field. Your dynamic action should be triggerd on change of an table row and subsequently set the date field to the current date.

Let me now if you need help on the dynamic action.

Comment: Can you guide me how to create dynamic action for this. I have tried to create dynamic action. but it is not worked.

Comment: No probs. However, guiding through such things is always a bit cumbersome over blog. If you put an example of what you have done so far on oracle.apex.com, I'll check what needs to be changed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have created a `before insert update` trigger and update `UPDATED_DATE` column via it.